# How to get better bracket matching/alignment in VIM?

Tags: vim

Is there any way to make VIM put the brackets in the right indentation? For example, whenever I type:

```
if (something)
    do something
```

and then I hit enter after "do something", to have it jump back in line with the if statement?  Also, when I go into insert mode, can I make it so it automatically jumps to the correct indentation level instead of staying at the beginning of the line?

Comment: What programming language are you coding in?

Answer (score 6):

For general C like languages you can do this in .vimrc

```
set smartindent
```

However vim can do better (and does like you ask for C), by enabling specific rules for various languages. To enable that I have:

```
filetype on
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
```

For more details search for "indent" in [my .vimrc](http://www.pixelbeat.org/settings/.vimrc)

Answer (score 2):

I use set cindent, it does the right thing every time.

(But I'm not sure if the "right thing" for C/C++ is what you're asking about.)

Answer (score 1):

```
:set si
```

turns on smart indenting.  You probably have to type control-D after a single line unbraced if like that, though.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
set smartindent
```

to your .vimrc file